# How can I sync my Outlook.com calendar to my Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: thunderbird, evolution, calendar

I have been unable to find a solution to this.

I use my outlook.com calendar and I want to Sync it to my Ubuntu desktop. I don't want to use my browser for it.

Please note that this is not an enterprise Outlook account.

Comment: You will need to use the evolution-ews plugin. https://sites.utexas.edu/glenmark/2021/02/01/how-to-setup-your-office-365-email-using-evolution-ews-linux/